# Streamwriter.WriteLine() is not writing everything. Strange output

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm writing a program to scrape links to my universities faculty bios pages. I'm using HTMLAgilityPack. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.IO;

namespace Get_Professor_Data
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("Links.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            string url, previousurl = "";
            char c = '@';
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            {
                HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(@"https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/index.php?sort=" + c);
                foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                {
                    c++;
                    url = link.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString();
                    //if (url == previousurl)
                    //    continue;
                    try
                    {
                        if (url.Substring(0, 25).Equals(@"/facultybios/profile.php?", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(@"https://www2.aus.edu" + url);
                            writer.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                    previousurl = url;
                }
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my output:

```
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jabdalla
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jsater
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jgriffin
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jfedtke
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jyounas
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jsqualli
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jboisvert
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jvinke
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jbaker
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jhassan
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jpalmer
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jkolo
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jmarch
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jinhyuk
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=giesen
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jvangorp
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jswanstrom
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jking
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jmontague
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jallee
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jkatsos
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jbley
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jwallis
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jgibbs
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=jroldan
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=
https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/profile.php?faculty=
https
```

For some strange reason only the links from the J page are printed. Some links are empty. The last line has only https (which is why I think the problem is with the writer and not the logic of my code). I've been trying to resolve this for a while with no luck.

These are the pages I'm scraping from: https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The fact that you're swallowing exceptions without any kind of logging or other action *may* be relevant. Why are you doing that? (Also, why are you explicitly calling `Close()` rather than using a `using` statement?)

Comment: @Jon Skeet I already know what the exceptions are. It's for links that are shorter than 25. I was writing them to console before but took it out. As for using, I'm not that experienced with C#. I changed it now.

Comment: That may be the exception in some cases... But if you're not logging it, and just assuming that's always the exception, you're potentially hiding real problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree 100% with Jon's observations: you should not need to catch exceptions at all (instead, just check the length before calling `Substring()`!), but for sure you should only catch an exception you *expect* to get. And you should use `using` to handle disposing both the `FileStream` object and the `StreamWriter` object (technically, the latter disposes the former for you, but IMHO it's just good to be explicit).

As for the actual problem, it seems to me that there's one obvious bug, and one possible bug:

- The obvious bug is that you are incrementing `c` (the variable you're using to select which page to scrape) in the wrong scope. That is, you increment its value once for every URL you process. Presumably, you actually want to increment that variable just before the loop, instead of inside of it.

I.e. instead of this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(@"https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/index.php?sort=" + c);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    c++;
```

you probably meant to write this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(@"https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/index.php?sort=" + c);
c++;
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
```

Or maybe even this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(@"https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/index.php?sort=" + (c++));
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
```

- The possible bug is that you initialize `c` to the character `@`. I didn't see anything on that page to suggest that would be a valid character to use; it looks like it will display links only when the `sort` parameter is set to a letter from `A` through `Z` (not case-sensitive).

With all of that in mind, IMHO a better way to write this code would be something like this:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Links.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)_
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    string url;
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        char c = (char)('A' + i);
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(@"https://www2.aus.edu/facultybios/index.php?sort=" + c);
        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            url = link.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString();
            if (url.Length > 25 &&
                url.Substring(0, 25).Equals(@"/facultybios/profile.php?", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(@"https://www2.aus.edu" + url);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Some of the things I did in my program weren't clear. '@' is just before 'A' in the ascii table but the way u wrote it made it more clear. This worked for me.